# How to plot pandas grouped values using pygal?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pygal

I have a csv like this:

```
name,version,color
AA,"version 1",yellow
BB,"version 2",black
CC,"version 3",yellow
DD,"version 1",black
AA,"version 1",green
BB,"version 2",green
FF,"version 3",green
GG,"version 3",red
BB,"version 3",yellow
BB,"version 2",red
BB,"version 1",black
```

I would like to draw a bar chart, which shows versions on x axis and an amount (number) of different colors on y axis.
So I want to group `DataFrame` by version, check which colors belong to a particular version, count colors and display the results on the [pygal bar chart](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/bar.html).

It should look similar to this:

[image]

What I tried so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(results)

new_df = df.groupby('version')['color'].value_counts()

bar_chart = pygal.Bar(width=1000, height=600,
                            legend_at_bottom=True, human_readable=True,
                            title='versions vs colors',
                            x_title='Version',
                            y_title='Number')
versions = []    

for index, row in new_df.iteritems():
    versions.append(index[0])
    bar_chart.add(index[1], row)

bar_chart.x_labels = map(str, versions)

bar_chart.render_to_file('bar-chart.svg')
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and can not match group of colors to proper version.

I also tried using `matplotlib.pyplot` and it works like a charm:

```
pd.crosstab(df['version'],df['color']).plot.bar(ax=ax)
plt.draw()
```

This works as well:

```
df.groupby(['version','color']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

But the generated chart is not accurate enough for me. I would like to have pygal chart.

I also checked:
[How to plot pandas groupby values in a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299305/how-to-plot-pandas-groupby-values-in-a-graph)
[How to plot a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005661/how-to-plot-a-pandas-dataframe)